# Copying files to usb on linux, how to know programmatically when files are commited and usb can be freed?

Tags: c++, linux, file, copy

When copying files on linux from a hdd to a usb, how to know when the process has been finished?

Comment: what method are you using to copy the files?

Comment: Perhaps `inotify` could be helpful. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inotify

Answer (score 0):

If you "umount" the USB device, all outstanding writes will be committed to the device. That does however assume you have sufficient privileges to do that.

Comment: That doesn't answer my question, i'm looking for a callback when copying has been finished.

Comment: As far as I'm aware, there is no such thing. In fact, it's entirely possible for the copy process to finish it's calls to "write file" long before the file has been committed to it's media. I guess you could try using things like O_DIRECT on the file and then call `fsync`.

Comment: @Code_So1dier  If you want a `callback`, then at least tell us what language you are using.  The question sounds like a script.

Comment: I'm using c++, the task is to copy arbitrary number of files to a usb device and tell when it is safe to remove it.